flutter firebase storage for windows
I have a  application flutter  use firebase sotrage  that works on Android, but I want to create a version that works on the desktop (Windows). There is a problem with the firebase options configuration because Windows does not appear in the file when using flutter cli.
I need a solution to make firebase work with Windows

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hey @Adham: Did you see my answer below? Anything else needed?

You might want to upgrade to the latest version of the flutterfire CLI, as that now shows Windows as an option: 
